# write a query calculates country-wise sales for all of the car models along with the total_sales generated for the year 2020 in ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

- car_model: id, name, price
- country: id, name
- Sales: model_id, country_id, quantity, sales_date

All the country-wise sale records of its cars in table sales, storing quantity sold on a particular date

need to write a query calculates country-wise sales for all of the car models along with the total_sales generated for the year 2020 in ascending order

```
select ct.name,cm.name,sl.quantity
from sales as sl inner join
     country as ct
     on sl.country_id=ct.id inner join
     car_model as cm
     on cm.id=sl.model_id 
where sl.sales_date BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '12-31-2020' order by quantity asc;
```

it's not working, can someone pls help with right solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, format your dates properly.  That is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Second, you need to **sum** the sales, so you need some sort of aggregation.

Third, I'm not sure what the difference is between "coutry-wise" sales and "total sales".  But here is a query you can work with:

```
select ct.name, cm.name, sum(sl.quantity)
from sales sl inner join
     country ct
     on sl.country_id = ct.id inner join
     car_model cm
     on cm.id = sl.model_id 
where sl.sales_date >= '2020-01-01' and
      sl.sales_date < '2021-01-01'
group by ct.name, cm.name with rollup;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
CT.name as country_name,
Cm.name as car_model,
Total_sales * price as total_sales from
(Select country_id,model_id,sum(quantity) as total_sales from sales
Where substring(sales_date,-4)='2020'
Group by country_id,model_id)sl
Inner join
Country as CT
On sl.country_id = CT.id
Inner join car_model as cm
On cm.id = sl.model_id
Order by CT.name,total_sales asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.name, m.name, 
sum(m. price * s. quantity) as total_ sales
from sales s
join country c on c.id=s. country_ id
join car_ model m on m.id=s. model_ id
where s. sales_ date like '%2020'
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: Why do you have spaces between the tablename aliases and the column names, that looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country.name, car_model.name, SUM(car_model.price*sales.quantity) AS total_sales
FROM sales
INNER JOIN country ON country.id=sales.country_id
INNER JOIN car_model ON sales.model_id=car_model.id
WHERE sales.sales_date like '%2020'
group by 1,2;
```

Comment: This looks like just a refactor of the other answer. If you want to fix syntax errors, you can edit the post. Just don't change too much or the edit will be rejected.